# Symfony 2 load different template depending on user agent properties

Tags: php, mobile, symfony, twig

Is it possible (and how) to

- determine if a user is using a mobile device
- force symfony 2 to load different template in that case
- *(and fall back the default html template)*

What id like to do is, to load different templates without modifying any controller.

**UPDATE**

It wasn't the detection part the real issue here, it's really nothing to do with symfony. It can be done (load different template) on a controller level:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $format = $this->isMobile() ? 'mob' : 'html';
    return $this->render('AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index.'.$format.'.twig');
}
```

But can it be done globally? Like a service, or something that execute before every request, and make changes in the templating rules.

Comment: I'm not sure the solution will be related to the framework. Have you checkout http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-php.htm#download ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, so I don't have a full solution but a little more than where to look for one :)

You can specify loaders (services) for templating item in app/config/config.yml

```
framework:
    esi:             { enabled: true }
    #translator:     { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: %kernel.debug%
    form:            true
    csrf_protection: true
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:       
        engines: 
           - twig 
        loaders:  [moby.loader]
    default_locale:  %locale%
    trust_proxy_headers: false
    session:         ~
```

Then define the mentioned loader service:

```
services:
    moby.loader:
        class: Acme\AppBundle\Twig\Loader\MobyFilesystemLoader
        arguments:    ["@templating.locator", "@service_container"]
```

After that define your loader service class:

```
namespace Acme\AppBundle\Twig\Loader;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\FilesystemLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\Storage\FileStorage;


class MobyFilesystemLoader extends FilesystemLoader
{
     protected $container;

     public function __construct($templatePathPatterns, $container) 
     {
         parent::__construct($templatePathPatterns);
         $this->container = $container;
     }

     public function load(\Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateReferenceInterface $template)
     {
         // Here you can filter what you actually want to change from html
         // to mob format
         // ->get('controller') returns the name of a controller
         // ->get('name')  returns the name of the template
         if($template->get('bundle') == 'AcmeAppBundle') 
         {
            $request = $this->container->get('request');
            $format = $this->isMobile($request) ? 'mob' : 'html';

            $template->set('format', $format);
         }

         try {
            $file = $this->locator->locate($template);
         } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            return false;
         }

         return new FileStorage($file);
      }

      /**
       * Implement your check to see if request is made from mobile platform
       */
       private function isMobile($request)
       {
           return true;
       }
 }
```

As you can see this isn't the full solution, but I hope that this, at least, points you to the right direction.

EDIT: Just found out that there is a bundle with mobile detection capabilities, with custom twig engine that renders template file depending on a device that sent request
[ZenstruckMobileBundle](http://zenstruck.com/projects/ZenstruckMobileBundle), although I never used it so... :)

Comment: FYI ZenstruckMobileBundle link is down. This works though: [http://zenstruck.com/projects/ZenstruckMobileBundle](http://zenstruck.com/projects/ZenstruckMobileBundle)

Comment: There is also https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle that gives you the tool for it too

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can use [LiipThemeBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle).

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize `kernel.view` event listener. This event comes to action when controller returns no response, only data. You can set reponse according to user agent property. For example

In your controller,

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $data = ... //data prepared for view
    $data['template_name'] = "AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index";

    return $data;
}
```

And the in your `kernel.view` event listener,

```
<?php

namespace Your\Namespace;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;

Class ViewListener
{
    /**
     * @var EngineInterface
     */
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function onKernelView(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getControllerResult(); //result returned by the controller
        $templateName = $data['template_name'];

        $format = $this->isMobile() ? 'mob' : 'html'; //isMobile() method may come from a injected service
        $response = $this->templating->renderResponse($templateName . "." . $format . "twig", $data);

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Service definition,

```
your_view_listener.listener:
    class: FQCN\Of\Listener\Class
    arguments:    [@templating]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.view, method: onKernelView }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what did the trick for me in Symfony 2.0:

Override twig.loader service so we can set our custom class:

```
twig.loader:
    class: Acme\AppBundle\TwigLoader\MobileFilesystemLoader
    arguments:
        locator:  "@templating.locator"
        parser:   "@templating.name_parser"
```

And create our custom class, that just sets "mob" format to the templates in case the client is a mobile device:

```
namespace Acme\AppBundle\TwigLoader;

use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Loader\FilesystemLoader;

class MobileFilesystemLoader extends FilesystemLoader
{

    public function findTemplate($template)
    {
        if ($this->isMobile()) {
            $template->set('format', 'mob');
        }

        return parent::findTemplate($template);
     }


    private function isMobile()
    {
        //do whatever to detect it
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that this is not best handled by the controller but by CSS media queries, and serving a separate stylesheet to different classes of devices based on the results of that CSS media query.
A good intro here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/introducing-media-queries.html

and I would try reading http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design in great detail. Some thinking has been done since the book was published, but it will get you headed the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences, you can but by specifying a format in the first place - check these [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#template-formats), they may be able to assist you

Answer (score 0):

I think is nothing to do with symfony. Templates are for the VIEW. You may achieve this by using different CSS for the same template to get different layout (template). I am using jQuery and CSS to handle different devices. You may want to look at some source code of the UI from http://themeforest.net/; specifically this [template](http://themeforest.net/item/hello-admin-template-desktops-tablets-mobiles/1271643?WT.ac=search_thumb&WT.seg_1=search_thumb&WT.z_author=OTWthemes). This is one handles different device.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle

I found it quite good compared to https://github.com/kbond/ZenstruckMobileBundle and https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle