# Symfony2: Change rendered view with a listener

Tags: view, symfony, rendering, listener

I would like to render different views in different context in my Symfony2 project.
I'm using multiple routes for the same actions and I would like to render a different page (view) but with the same controller.
For example I have:

```
@Route("/articles/show", name="articles_show")
@Route("/mobile/articles/show", name="mobile_articles_show")
```

**Both routes** are using **the same action** : ArticlesController:showAction(), but should render 2 differents templates (for mobile users and regulars ones).

```
show.html.twig
mobile.show.html.twig
```

I do not want to use a if statement or whatever in my controller, so I created a listener (similar to a preExecute function)

Here is a part or my **config.yml** that defines my **listener**

```
services:
    controller.pre_execute_listener:
        class: MyProject\MyBundle\Listener\ControllerListener
        arguments: ["@security.context", "@doctrine", "@router", "@session"]
        tags:- { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: preExecute }
```

I was thinking about doing something like that in the listener **preExecute function**:

```
if(substr($route,0,7) == 'mobile_'){
    $view = 'mobile.'.$view;
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot find a way to get **$view** or update the view "on the fly", just before it's rendered.

I hope my question is clear enough, thanks in advance, any idea is welcome :)

J.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the **solution**:

First I have to listen to **kernel.view**, not kernel.controller.

Then I use the "**@templating**" service (Thanks Marko Jovanovic for the hint)

So here is my new config.yml:

```
services:
    controller.pre_execute_listener:
        class: MyProject\MyBundle\Listener\ControllerListener
        arguments: ["@templating"]
        tags:
                - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.view, method: preExecute }
```

Finally here is my listener **preExecute function**

```
public function preExecute(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event){
    //result returned by the controller
    $data = $event->getControllerResult();

    /* @var $request  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request */
    $request =  $event->getRequest();       
    $template = $request->get('_template');
    $route = $request->get('_route');

    if(substr($route,0,7) == 'mobile_'){
        $newTemplate = str_replace('html.twig','mobile.html.twig',$template);

        //Overwrite original template with the mobile one
        $response = $this->templating->renderResponse($newTemplate, $data);
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

J.

Answer (score 4):

Worth noting: The accepted solution doesn't actually work if you directly return a `Response`-object (e.g. when you call `$this->render()`), because the `kernel.view` event is not fired in that case:

> If the controller doesn't return a Response object, then the kernel dispatches another event - `kernel.view`.
>
> *— see [Symfony's HTTP Kernel Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-view-event)*

I couldn't work out a way around this, but found another interesting solution for the same problem:
You could simply extend twig's render engine like the [ZenstruckMobileBundle](https://github.com/kbond/ZenstruckMobileBundle/blob/master/Twig/TwigEngine.php) does or write your own file locator like the [LiipThemeBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle).

[edit:] Alternatively you could also override the `TemplateNameParser`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add "@templating" service as argument for the controller.pre_execute_listener.

Comment: The service helps me rendering a new one, not to get the current one.
I can't find a way to get the "current" view.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I just assumed that @templating contains a name of a current one (stupid of me) :(. Anyway, I see that you solved the problem, so you can post the answer yourself and accept it. P.S. If you need alternative way of overriding templates see my answer on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257676/symfony-2-load-different-template-depending-on-user-agent-properties/11939369#11939369

Answer (score 0):

It seems your device detection is done before you come to your route, so I bet you expect that mobile user will use the mobile routes thanks to some detection before the request, this seems to be painful to deal with in every templates and url generation.

May be better to detect device either before or later (thanks to [Categorizr](http://www.brettjankord.com/2012/01/16/categorizr-a-modern-device-detection-script/) or [some nice apache configuration](https://github.com/kbond/ZenstruckMobileBundle#reference)) but not relying on used route for the mobile detection.

An integration of Categorizr with [that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12000005/236281) of calling templates rendering might be nice.

Then using [a nice bundle for using the right templates/themes](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle) or [using one which provides some more generic functions](https://github.com/kbond/ZenstruckMobileBundle)