# Twig/Symfony2: Search multiple template directories?

Tags: templates, symfony, twig

What I want to do is quite easy, but I did not found the solution, yet. In my application I want to organize all templates by theme, language and scope. For that it is neccessary to build and search multiple paths for the right template.

For example the Acme:Default:editAction is requested and the Acme:Default:edit.html.twig template should be loaded by default.

```
APP_PATH/src/Acme/DefaultBundle/Resources/views/Default/edit.html.twig
```

Now I want to change this behaviour and search in multiple paths for that template in the given order.

```
1. VIEWS_PATH/%theme%/%lang%/%scope%/Default/edit.html.twig
2. VIEWS_PATH/%theme%/%lang%/Default/edit.html.twig
3. VIEWS_PATH/%theme%/Default/edit.html.twig
4. VIEWS_PATH/Default/edit.html.twig
```

What is the easiest way to do that? Add the Paths at some point in config or in an event listener or override the TemplateLoaderClass?

Please no recommendations to any Bundles. I just want to understand how Symfony(2.1)/Twig works at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Bind an event listener that takes the Templating service as an argument and modify the template name on the kernel.view event.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12403233/1649758 for a code sample of this.

Comment: I should parse the path again and rebuild it? Is there no way to inject the subpaths into the existing logic?