# Set templates defined on DB

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've a project with backend and frontend.
In the backend I want to add one option to change template
The style is defined on base.html.twig on this line:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/themes/default.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color"/>
```

My question is how can I change the style when I load this file.
The template option will be stored on database.

EDIT:
In the moment I'm doing like this: I created an action on default controller to return a new Response with the template defined on DB, then in base.html.twig.

```
{{ render(controller("AdminPageBundle:Default:getTemplateAdmin")) }}
```

it works like this, but I don't think is the best way to do this

Comment: do you mean that you want to know  how to load a different stylesheet for each template?

Comment: In my css/themes directory I have a few css, like default, blue, red.... And I have one column on Settings DB with colour of the theme, and I want to load the colour from DB and apply the right stylesheet. I'm doing this like in my edit, it returns the colour from DB, but I don't think is the right way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that I understood the question. I assume that you're looking for a way to 'bind' the correct stylesheet depending on settings from the database, the latter being already solved

Twig provides an OOP like inheritence that you may leverage to make this work.

Here's a solution in three steps :

Step one : write a "theme aware" action. In the controller

...

```
public function adminAction(){
    //get the settings information, this is hardcoded for the sake of esample
    //you may as well fetch this from the DB
    $themeSettings = array('style'=>'blue');

    //render the template and inject the variable
    return $this->render('AdminPageBundle:Default:template.html.twig',
        array('theme'=>$themeSettings));

}
```

Step2 : create a base template with the default theme (failsafe)
//let's call it base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
{% block stylesheets %}
<link href="{{ asset('css/themes/default.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
{% endblock %}
....
</head>
...
```

Step3 : Override the 'stylesheets' block in the theme-aware template
//template.html.twig:

```
{# make it a child of base.html.twig #}
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{# override the stylesheets block #}
{% block stylesheets %}
{# include what you already have in the parent template (link to default.css) #}
{{ parent }}
{# add your own theme from the database (using the 'theme' variable from the controller #}
<link href="{{ asset('css/themes/'~ theme.style ~ '.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
{% endblock %}
```

With this example, rendering 'template.html.twig' will load the stylesheet at '/css/themes/blue.css'.

You may as well implement this directly in the base template without relying on inheritence, but I'm assuming that some templates are theme-aware and some aren't. Inheritence provides flexibility to implement this feature only where you need it.

Of course, there are several other ways to solve the problem. [Writing a custom twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) to handle theming would be the right thing to do for a reliable long term solution, especially if theming is not just about loading a stylesheet. You may also write an event handler (for the kernel.view event) to modify the template or inject theme settings just before rendering. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12403233/1654371) shows an example.