# Symfony2 twig mobile template fallback

Tags: symfony, mobile, twig, fallback

I need a simple way to fallback on a default template if no mobile version exists.

With some regular expressions I recognize mobile platforms and want to render a template with the following pattern:

```
<template_name>.mobile.html.twig
```

But if this template doesn't exist, I want it to automatically fallback on:

```
<template_name>.html.twig
```

which always exists.

I tried nearly all the answers from this post:
[Symfony 2 load different template depending on user agent properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257676/symfony-2-load-different-template-depending-on-user-agent-properties)
but with no success. Unfortunately there are no version numbers referenced.

At the moment I am trying to copy and modify the default twig loader.

By the way, What I want to achieve with this is the possibility to deploy different templates for mobile devices by just adding a template of the same name and adding a .mobile.

**UPDATE:**

http://www.99bugs.com/handling-mobile-template-switching-in-symfony2/
This one is also a good approach. It modifies the format property of the request object which affects the automatic template guessing when you don't specify a template in the controller with the render function (or annotation) but just return an array.

Resulting template name:

```
view/<controller>/<action>.<request format>.<engine>
```

So you could switch the request format from html to mobile.html based on the device detection.
The downside of this is that every template needs a mobile.html pendant (which then could just include the non-mobile version if not needed).

**UPDATE:**

Besides using a custom templating provider there is also the possibility to [hook into the kernel.view event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-view-event).

Comment: You can make a listener to catch nonexistent template errors. You can do it on the controller level (I'd do it here) by returning the response with a different template or redirecting to a mobile only url or even on the template with some clever variables or JS. You could probably even achieve it on the routing level. You can define a custom loader service. The possibilities are endless : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a service to handle it and then use it in the same way that you do the templating service like so..

Create a service with the templating and request service injected into it..

Service (YAML)

```
acme.templating: 
    class: Acme\AcmeBundle\Templating\TemplatingProvider
    scope: request
    arguments:
        - @templating
        - @request // I assume you use request in your platform decision logic,
                   // otherwise you don't needs this or the scope part
        - 'html'
```

Class

```
class TemplatingProvider
{
    private $fallback;
    private $platform;
    ... __construct($templating, $request, $fallback) etc

    private function setPlatform() ... Your platform decision logic

    private function getPlatform()
    {
        if (null === $this->platform) {
            $this->setPlatform();
        }

        return $this->platform;
    }

    private function getTemplateName($name, $platform)
    {
        if ($platform === 'html') {
            return $name;
        }

        $template = explode('.', $name);

        $template = array_merge(
            array_slice($template, 0, -2),
            array($platform),
            array_slice($template, -2)
        );

        return implode('.', $template);
    }

    public function renderResponse($name, array $parameters = array())
    {
        $newname = $this->getTemplateName($name, $this->getPlatform());

        if ($this->templating->exists($newname)) {
            return $this->templating->render($newname);
        }

        return $this->templating->renderResponse($this->getTemplateName(
                                                $name, $this->fallback));
    }
```

And then you could just call your templating service instead of the current one..

```
return $this->container->get('acme.templating')
                          ->renderResponse('<template_name>.html.twig', array());
```

Comment: Thats kind of the way I thought of. Thanks!

Comment: Well... as i am trying out your solution I get a little bit unsatisfied. I really would like to obtain the automatich template guessing based on controller and action name when only returning an array in the controller. But i thinks this way it is ok for now.

Comment: Do you mean when using annotations for the template?

Comment: Yes and i just ran into another problem.
`The controller must return a response (<!DOCTYPE html>... given`
The render function of the TemplatingProvider doesn't seem to return a response object, instead it returns the plan html text although it returns the return value of the native render function. Any idea?

Comment: Well, ok... the render function simply is supposed to return just the html. Only The shortcut $this->render inside aof controller wraps it into a response.

Comment: `$this->templating->renderResponse()` is the solution.

Comment: You could change it from `render` to `renderResponse` in both the method name and the method it calls in the current templating jobby.... And you already found it anyways. I'll update.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works as expected now. I think the only other possibility now would be to write a custom twig loader but I think I am just as satisfied now.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you check if the template exist before ?

```
if ( $this->get('templating')->exists('<templatename>.html.twig') ) {
    //  return  this->render(yourtemplate)
} else {
    // return your default template
}
```

**OR :**

You can create a generic method, to insert in your root controller like :

```
public function renderMobile($templateName, $params)
{
    $templateShortName = explode('.html.twig', $templateName)[0];
    $mobileName = $templateShortName.'.mobile.html.twig';
    if ( $this->get('templating')->exists($mobileName) ) {

        return $this->renderView($mobileName, $params);
    } else {
        return $this->renderView($templateName, $params)
    }
}
```

with this you can do :

```
return $this->renderMobile('yourtemplate', [yourparams]);
```

Comment: Yes this would work, but i am looking for an automatic way of checking this outside of the controller. I Tried to override the twig loader but several different approaches failed and the documentation on this is not very detailed.

Comment: Best solution so far i think, maybe i should create a service for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by harnessing the bundle inheritance properties in Symfony2 http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

- create a bundle which holds your desktop templates (AcmeDemoDesktopBundle)
- create a bundle which will hold your mobile templates (AcmeDemoMobileBundle) and mark the parent as AcmeDemoDesktopBundle

Then when you render a template simply call AcmeDemoMobileBundle:: - if the template exists, it'll be rendered otherwise you'll neatly fall back to the desktop version. No extra code, listeners or anything none-obvious required.

The downside of this of course is that you move your templates out of the individual bundles.

Comment: Good idea, but i don't see a way to use it only if the device is a mobile one.

Comment: Also there would be no way of accessing the none mobile templates (if a mobile version exists) if you wanted to show the full page.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer - the issue suggests you already have that, this then is just a neat way of falling back rather than trying to use different template names.

Comment: @Qoop - this assumes that there is a mobile switch already and that you only want the mobile templates, but good point.

Answer (score 0):

The fallback behavior you describe isn't that easy to implement (we found out the hard way..). Good news is we wanted the same setup as you ask for and ended up using the [LiipThemeBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle) for this purpose. It allows you to have different "themes" based on for example a device. It will do the fallback part for you.

For example:

Rendering a template:

`@BundleName/Resources/template.html.twig`

Will render and fallback to in order:

- `app/Resources/themes/phone/BundleName/template.html.twig`
- `app/Resources/BundleName/views/template.html.twig`
- `src/BundleName/Resources/themes/phone/template.html.twig`
- `src/BundleName/Resources/views/template.html.twig`

Edit: so with this approach you can have default templates that will always be the final fallback and have a special template for mobile where you need it.