# symfony template different for language

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working on a project and I want add languages - I don't want to change in any controller - switching template for other language - found this solution :

[Symfony 2 load different template depending on user agent properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257676/symfony-2-load-different-template-depending-on-user-agent-properties)

I setup it :

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: grek
 * Date: 15.01.14
 * Time: 15:41
 */

namespace ed\siteBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\FilesystemLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\Storage\FileStorage;

class templateLangLoader extends FilesystemLoader{

    protected $container;

    public function __construct($templatePathPatterns, $container)
    {
        parent::__construct($templatePathPatterns);
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(\Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateReferenceInterface $template)
    {

        $translatedBundles = ['eddiscoveryBundle','edpartnerBundle','edregisterBundle','siteBundle','userBundle'];
        if(in_array($template->get('bundle'),$translatedBundles))
        {
            //$request = $this->container->get('request');

        }

        try {
            $file = $this->locator->locate($template);

        echo "<BR>$file";
           /*
            print_r([
                $template->getLogicalName()
                ,$template->getPath()
                , var_dump($template,1)
                , $file
            ]);
*/

        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            return false;
        }

        return new FileStorage($file);
    }



}
```

and i get onsite :

```
/home/grek/public_html/edpartner/src/ed/discoveryBundle/Resources/views/Default/pl_listItem.html.twig
/home/grek/public_html/edpartner/src/ed/discoveryBundle/Resources/views/Default/pl_header.html.twig
/home/grek/public_html/edpartner/src/ed/discoveryBundle/Resources/views/Default/pl_list.html.twig
/home/grek/public_html/edpartner/src/ed/discoveryBundle/Resources/views/Default/pl_fullPage.html.twig
/home/grek/public_html/edpartner/src/ed/discoveryBundle/Resources/views/Default/pl_listItemDemo.html.twig
/home/grek/public_html/edpartner/app/Resources/views/pl_ajax-layout.html.twig
/home/grek/public_html/edpartner/app/Resources/views/pl_clean.html.twig
/home/grek/public_html/edpartner/app/Resources/views/pl_base.html.twig
```

Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
500 Internal Server Error - Exception

very strange is - template name - i rename all templates add pl_ surfix but on code i not change but synfony self find templates ?

i have in code : 
$this->render('eddiscoveryBundle:Default:list.html.twig')

symfony look - pl_list.html.twig how it quest it ? i want it but i think to i must change - this is self change and error Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

New : 
i rename template from 
/home/grek/public_html/edpartner/src/ed/discoveryBundle/Resources/views/Default/pl_listItem.html.twig
to 
/home/grek/public_html/edpartner/src/ed/discoveryBundle/Resources/views/Default/asdasdasdasdasasd_listItem.html.twig
and i see this name on echo "
$file"; without any change ? how it possible ?

so how to correct rename it now on code ?

Update 2:

is change loader :

```
  public function load(\Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateReferenceInterface $template)
    {

        $translatedBundles = ['eddiscoveryBundle','edpartnerBundle','edregisterBundle','siteBundle','userBundle'];



        if(in_array($template->get('bundle'),$translatedBundles))
        {

            var_dump($template);
            $request = $this->container->get('request');

        }

        $file = $this->locator->locate($template);

        return new FileStorage($file);

    }
```

and rename all templates to original without pl_

get (site work)  first :

```
object(Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference)[1268]
  protected 'parameters' => 
    array (size=5)
      'bundle' => string 'eddiscoveryBundle' (length=17)
      'controller' => string 'Default' (length=7)
      'name' => string 'fullPage' (length=8)
      'format' => string 'html' (length=4)
      'engine' => string 'twig' (length=4)
```

rename template add pl_ - without any change of code :

and (site not work) get :

```
    object(Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference)[335]
  protected 'parameters' => 
    array (size=5)
      'bundle' => string 'eddiscoveryBundle' (length=17)
      'controller' => string 'Default' (length=7)
      'name' => string 'pl_fullPage' (length=11)
      'format' => string 'html' (length=4)
      'engine' => string 'twig' (length=4)
```

and site crash -  Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
500 Internal Server Error - Exception

so how to rename filename to pl_ - its is self renamed and crash :)

this example use FilesystemLoader - maybe is possible to use - Twig_LoaderInterface i found  somethink on this in doc but dont see this class or example how to override it in symfony ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change anything. You can have 1 template/controller for all the languages as long as you do it right...

Read the docs for more info on translations [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html)

Comment: i read it - but i want somethink more - auto template rename for diffrent language - i found somethink simmilar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257676/symfony-2-load-different-template-depending-on-user-agent-properties