# twig loader replace make Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed 500 Internal Server Error - Exception

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Hi I try use own loader to rename template.

add to config :

```
 templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        loaders:  [template.lang.loader]
```

service definition :

```
services:
    template.lang.loader:
      class: ed\siteBundle\Service\templateLangLoader
      arguments:    ["@templating.locator", "@service_container"]
```

loader from first example in this topic : [Symfony 2 load different template depending on user agent properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257676/symfony-2-load-different-template-depending-on-user-agent-properties)

Maybe is for other symfony version ?

here is loader

```
<?php

namespace ed\siteBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\FilesystemLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\Storage\FileStorage;

class templateLangLoader extends FilesystemLoader{

    protected $container;

    public function __construct($templatePathPatterns, $container)
    {

        parent::__construct($templatePathPatterns);
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(\Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateReferenceInterface $template)
    {
        // Here you can filter what you actually want to change from html
        // to mob format
        // ->get('controller') returns the name of a controller
        // ->get('name')  returns the name of the template
        $translatedBundles = ['eddiscoveryBundle','edpartnerBundle','edregisterBundle','siteBundle','userBundle'];
        if(in_array($template->get('bundle'),$translatedBundles))
        {

            /**
             * TODO: rename template
             */


        }

        try {
            $file = $this->locator->locate($template);
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            return false;
        }

        return new FileStorage($file);
    }

    /**
     * Implement your check to see if request is made from mobile platform
     */
    private function isMobile($request)
    {
        return true;
    }



}
```

when I run site  I get :

```
 Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
500 Internal Server Error - Exception
```

How this loader should look ? (when I unregister this loader - it work when I register have this error.

I see in twig api - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/master/index.html it use  Twig_LoaderInterface, not  FilesystemLoader - with and how should I use

UPDATE 1

when I remove or rename - load function - still have Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed so maybe this is not compatibile loader ?

UPDATE 2
I try replace twig.loader

add to my bundle services

```
services:
    twig.loader:
      class: ed\siteBundle\Service\templateLangLoader
      arguments:    ["@templating.locator", "@service_container"]
```

and remove from config loader now look

```
 templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme

    default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

but loader is not called - I put die('test'); to load() method and don't see it

My target is : rename template (add lang code as surfix)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to the config.yml:

```
parameters: 
    twig.loader.class: YOUR_CLASS
```

Here are some more details for configuration (You just have to translate them into yml):
https://github.com/fabpot/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/config/twig.xml

Comment: parameters:
    twig.loader.class: template.lang.loader not work - i dont know but first version work - loaders:  [template.lang.loader] call this class - when i put die('test') have ok :) so class ic called but throw this exepstion - even if it this class is empty so mayby this is incompatibile loader ?

Comment: where is the exception thrown? Which line and which class/file?

Comment: ok that doesn't help so much at the moment. What is your goal? What do you want to do with your workaround? Perhaps there's a complete another solution for this.

Comment: i only want in one place rename templates - add $currentLang_ as template surfix - how where do it ?

Comment: Why don't you create a templating service and only use the service to render views? You could inject the templating engine and create setters for the needed attributes. In this service you could manage the renaming.

Comment: ok i do this- but i must replace code in all controllers to use my template not default , i try this loader to dont do it