# Symfony 2: Load custom Twig block in application

Tags: forms, symfony, templates, twig

I've some customised blocks used to render my forms, one file for the frontend and another one for the backend of my application:

- form_layout_frontend.html.twig
- form_layout_backend.html.twig

These files works the same way as the default twig form template.
Those files contain the same block names but their content is of course different.

My question is about how to load the appropriate file depending on where I'm in the application (frontend/ backend).

Till now I only had one file and it was loaded from the config.yml as below:

`# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    form:
        resources:
            - 'TravelyoAdminBundle:Form:form_layout_frontend.html.twig'
            - 'TravelyoCoreBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'`

I read it was possible to do it on the twig level by using something like:

```
{% form_theme form 'TravelyoAdminBundle::Form/form_layout_frontend.html.twig' %}
```

at the top of my view, but I can't do it on every twig and as some twigs my contain different form name I cannot put it in a parent view that will be extended by every frontend file for example.

I read the documentation but honnestly didn't get much out of it ... (http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you reviewed the information in [this question][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257676/symfony-2-load-different-template-depending-on-user-agent-properties

Comment: Not sure it is the same. What I need is to be able to autoload this form template in any template that will be loaded from a part of my app. In you link it seem to be described how to catch that moment when templates are loaded (I need to give it a try) but how do I add an additional template to be loaded in top if the one my controller will need to render. Not sure I'm clear...

Comment: I'm not sure how to phrase that. But I'm not looking for dynamically loading a template (twig view) but rather to dynamically load the twig file that are injected in the view. Like by default the form_layout_div.twig is loaded I want another file to be loaded instead, but dynamically based on some routing data.

Comment: Are your frontend and backend templates reusing the same templates or something?  It seems like you could just have a base template for both the frontend and backend where you load the corresponding twig that you need.